# Show that the group $H_{\omega}^{ev}(X)$ depends only on the cohomology de-Rhan class $[\omega]$.

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\Omega^{\bullet}(X)$ be the space of differential forms on a smooth manifold $X$. Let $\omega$ be an odd degree form. Consider

$$d_{\omega}:\Omega^{\bullet}(X) \to \Omega^{\bullet}(X) $$

such that $d_{\omega}(\eta)= d\eta + \omega\wedge\eta$.
Now consider the twisted cohomology group

$$H_{\omega}^{ev}(X):= \ker(d^{ev}_{\omega})/ {\rm Im}(d^{odd}_{\omega})$$
where $d_{\omega}^{ev}:\Omega^{2k}(X) \to \Omega^{2k}(X)$, and $d^{odd}_{\omega}$ is defined in a similar way.

> Show that the group $H_{\omega}^{ev}(X)$ depends only on the cohomology de-Rhan class $[\omega]$.

Can anyone provide me an idea of what this question is asking for?

Comment: I believe the question is:  If $[\omega] = [\nu]$, then is $H^{ev}_\omega$ isomorphic to $H^{ev}_{\nu}$?  But I think you need $\omega$ to be closed for the question to make sense.

Comment: yes, the form has to be closed for the question to make sense. Thank you for pointing that out. However, how to show that there is such isomorphism between $H^{ev}_{\omega}$ and $H^{ev}_{\nu}$ ?

Comment: In the answer you linked from, I explain why $H_0^{ev} \cong H_{dW}^{ev}$. Now, you want to show that $H_{\omega}^{ev} \cong H_{\omega+dW}^{ev}$. What happens when you mimic that proof?